# how to get specific parts in a page using preg_match_all

Tags: php

Hello I use preg_match_all function to grab things on a page but when i tried to grab some specific parts like details part it sends me an array !

code structure on that page is

```
<div class="f slp">DETAILS I WANT TO GET</div>
```

previously for grab urls n titles I used a code like

```
//so this gets URLs in href=""
preg_match_all('/a href="([^"]+)" class=l.+?>.+?<\/a>/',$scraped,$results);
```

but this time I want to grab some details on that page under the structure of

```
<div class="f slp">DETAILS I WANT TO GET</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
preg_match_all("#<div class=\"f slp\">(.*?)<\/div>#si", $source, $match);

foreach($match[1] as $val) {
    echo $val."<br>";
}
```

Comment: thnx it works but it ignores some details and displays extractly details matches with the given code above but in some places it's code looks like this 

<div class="f slp"><em>xxxx</em>xxxx<b>xxxx</b></div>

how to ignore those tags and get all the details( all the Xs)

Answer (score 1):

Please check out [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) a very easy to use library that makes it pretty easy to extract content from html.

```
// from the documentation
$html = str_get_html("<div>foo <b>bar</b></div>");
$e = $html->find("div", 0);
echo $e->tag; // Returns: " div"
echo $e->outertext; // Returns: " <div>foo <b>bar</b></div>"
echo $e->innertext; // Returns: " foo <b>bar</b>"
echo $e->plaintext; // Returns: " foo bar"
```

read more in [manual](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm)