# get content from specific format between for body of email

Tags: php, regex

Get data between specific line using `preg_match_all` in php
I'm using this function but I don't get perfect result.
Please help me.

```
$t = '
**********REPLY BELOW THIS LINE**********


how can i do this can you please tell me. 


**********REPLY ABOVE THIS LINE**********
lkasdflkj;ladskjflk
aksdfj;lkajs;dflj
asdflkj;ladskjflklaskdjf;lkjasd
lajsdf;lkjasd;ladskjflklaskdjfladskjf
lasdflkjlkasd
ladskjflklaskdjfladskjf
**********REPLY BELOW THIS LINE**********


we will do this task


**********REPLY ABOVE THIS LINE**********
';
if(preg_match_all('/\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\REPLY BELOW THIS LINE\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*(.*?)\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\REPLY ABOVE THIS LINE\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*/',$body,$match)) {            
            var_dump($match[1]);
    }
```

Comment: Have you heard about a DOTALL modifier? Add `s` at the end of the regex (after `/`). See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/kG6wQ1/2).

Comment: explode string to array and then find

Comment: Thank you so much for contribution, I got answer my self [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10458185/how-to-get-specific-parts-in-a-page-using-preg-match-all)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew True - plus - I was wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my answer. Thank you.

```
preg_match_all('#\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*REPLY BELOW THIS LINE\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*(.*?)\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*REPLY ABOVE THIS LINE\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*#si',$t,$match);            

var_dump($match[1]);
```